# Parse JSON from HTTParty using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I am  implementation of data from a `JSON` file to a Ruby on Rails    application by using `HTTparty` gem, but I am getting Error `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

I refered this tutorial [link](http://www.mattmorgante.com/technology/httparty)

My json data,

```
{
    "restaurant_name": "Restaurant 3",
    "address": "xyz address",
    "country": "United States",
    "currency": "USD",
    "client_key": "12345",
    "client_name": "Client 3",
    "client_email": "test3@mail.com",
    "client_phone": "9876",
    "product_tier": "tier1",
    "brand_logo_large": {
        "ID": 37,
        "id": 37,
        "title": "bait-al-bahar-logo-design",
        "filename": "bait-al-bahar-logo-design.png",
        "filesize": 105071,
        "url": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bait-al-bahar-logo-design.png",
        "link": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/projects/res-1-client-1/bait-al-bahar-logo-design/",
        "alt": "",
        "author": "1",
        "description": "",
        "caption": "",
        "name": "bait-al-bahar-logo-design",
        "status": "inherit",
        "uploaded_to": 35,
        "date": "2019-01-04 11:11:48",
        "modified": "2019-01-04 11:13:01",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "mime_type": "image/png",
        "type": "image",
        "subtype": "png",
        "icon": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-includes/images/media/default.png",
        "width": 600,
        "height": 500,
        "sizes": {
            "thumbnail": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bait-al-bahar-logo-design-150x150.png",
            "thumbnail-width": 150,
            "thumbnail-height": 150,
            "medium": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bait-al-bahar-logo-design-300x250.png",
            "medium-width": 300,
            "medium-height": 250,
            "medium_large": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bait-al-bahar-logo-design.png",
            "medium_large-width": 600,
            "medium_large-height": 500,
            "large": "http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/bait-al-bahar-logo-design.png",
            "large-width": 600,
            "large-height": 500
        }
    }
```

In model,

```
include HTTParty
```

In controller

```
def index  
  require 'httparty'
  @category = HTTParty.get(
    'http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-json/data/v2/projects?client_key=12345',
    :headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
  )
end
```

In gemfile,

```
gem 'httparty'
gem 'json'
```

In view,

```
<%@category.each do |category|%>
<%=category["restaurant_name"]%>
<%=category["country"]%>
<%=category["currency"]%>
<%=category["usd"]%>
<%=category["client_key"]%>
<%=category["client_name"]%>
<%=category["client_email"]%>
<%=category["client_phone"]%>
<%=category["product_tier"]%>
<%=category["brand_logo_large"]%>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTTParty.get` returns an encapsulated response type of class `HTTParty::Response`, you need to retrieve the `parsed response` from that by:

```
response = HTTParty.get(
  'http://codekyt.in/froodle-wp/wp-json/data/v2/projects?client_key=12345',
  :headers =>{'Content-Type' => 'application/json'}
)
@category = response.parsed_response # this will return the json.
```

Also you do not need to iterate on `@category` in your case, the json object is singular and you can directly use it:

```
<%=@category["restaurant_name"]%>
<%=@category["country"]%>
<%=@category["currency"]%>
<%=@category["usd"]%>
<%=@category["client_key"]%>
<%=@category["client_name"]%>
<%=@category["client_email"]%>
<%=@category["client_phone"]%>
<%=@category["product_tier"]%>
<%=@category["brand_logo_large"]%>
```

Comment: @kiddorails no my json object is not sigular for example purpose i show only one data

Comment: In which case u can iterate. But the sample json you have provided and on the mentioned URL is singular.

Comment: @kiddorails now getting same error no implicit conversion of String into Integer.

Comment: @rajD on which line? in parsed_response? what does `response.code` give you?

Comment: i use this way but same error :<%= puts @category.collect {|p| "#{p[:restaurant_name]}: #{p[:country]}"}%>

Comment: Modify with this one <%= puts @category.collect {|p| "#{p["restaurant_name"]}: #{p["country"]}"}%>

Comment: @rajD the problem is you are expecting this to be an array, when the response is singular and is a hash. For instance, this should work -  `[@category].collect {|p| "#{p['restaurant_name']}: #{p['country']}"}`

Comment: @Rohan Hey. Can you connect with me on my profile's linkedin?